# Android ORMLite. LEFT join. WHERE clause

Tags: android, ormlite

```
QueryBuilder<Answer, Integer> queryBuilder = helper.getAnswerDao().queryBuilder();
QueryBuilder<Question, Integer> questionQueryBuilder = helper.getQuestionDao().queryBuilder();

questionQueryBuilder.where().eq(Question.TYPE_COLUMN_NAME, "table");            
queryBuilder.leftJoin(questionQueryBuilder);

queryBuilder.where().eq(Answer.PICKED_COLUMN_NAME, true);

pickedAnswers = queryBuilder.query();
```

Generated SQL statement:

```
SELECT `Answers`.* 
FROM `Answers`
    LEFT JOIN `Questions` ON `Answers`.`questionId` = `Questions`.`id`
WHERE `Answers`.`picked` = 1
    AND (`Questions`.`type` = 'table' )
```

This query returns empty result set due to 'AND' logical operation. This is default behaviour of ORMLite. Is any possibility to change where clause conjuction with 'OR' operation?

I have tried: `queryBuilder.where().or()` before `queryBuilder.where().eq(Answer.PICKED_COLUMN_NAME, true)` and `queryBuilder.where().or(2)` after all `where()` methods.

Answer (score 5):

There is `leftJoinOr` method which does exactly what I need. It builds where clause with OR logical operation.